# How to load an image from MongoDB into a PIL object?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-imaging-library, gridfs

I store some images in a MongoDB database using GridFS. I'd like to load them directly into a PIL object without saving on the hard drive.

My try is:

```
    f_id = mydb.images.files.find_one({ "filename" : "moto.jpeg" },{ "_id" : 1 })
    data = fs.get(f_id['_id']).read()

    img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
```

But I get error: OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff3aeb03bf8>

I have also tried BytesIO_object.seek(0), but with no avail. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please show the first 20-30 bytes in hex of your data variable, e.g. data[:30]

Answer (score 0):

[Image.open takes a filepath as parameter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) and not the contents of the image.

Pass the filepath to Image.open and it should work

Comment: According to the documentation, it can take a file object as well. There is no filepath, because I load the image from a database.